# Free space in my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled

Tags: disk-usage

[image]I just bought Dell XPS 13 model with 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD and Ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled. When I click on Properties, it shows 425gb free space. May I know why?

Results of `sudo parted -l` :

```
Number   Start     End    Size  File system  Name                  Flags  
 1      1049kB   786MB   786MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2       787MB  6156MB  5369MB  fat32        Basic Data Partition  msftres
 3      6156MB   512GB   506GB  ext4
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the terminal and run `sudo parted -l` to show all the partitions that Ubuntu can see. The results of `sudo parted -l` show a table that looks like this.

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST9500420AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      32.3kB  41.1MB  41.1MB  primary   fat16           diag
 2      41.9MB  15.8GB  15.7GB  primary   ntfs            boot
 3      15.8GB  99.7GB  83.9GB  primary   ntfs
 4      99.7GB  500GB   400GB   extended                  lba
 5      99.7GB  102GB   2147MB  logical   fat32           lba
 7      102GB   176GB   73.8GB  logical   ext4
 6      176GB   492GB   316GB   logical   ext4
 8      492GB   500GB   8389MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

The size of each partition is listed in the 4th column. The partition's size can give you a clue about what it is used for. One of the partitions may contain software that was bundled by Dell along with the XPS 13 laptop.

Your results of `sudo parted -l` are as follows:

```
Number   Start     End    Size  File system  Name                  Flags  
 1      1049kB   786MB   786MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2       787MB  6156MB  5369MB  fat32        Basic Data Partition  msftres
 3      6156MB   512GB   506GB  ext4
```

The above results show that 5.4GB are used as a Basic Data Partition and 0.8GB are used as a EFI System Partition for the boot loader. This accounts for some of the missing space. The rest of the space that isn't free space is taken up by the Ubuntu installation, installed packages, and saved user files in the user's home directory.

The next thing to do is to see what's using 81GB of the 506GB in your ext4 Ubuntu partition graphically. For new installations of Ubuntu 18.04 a swap file is created by default instead of a swap partition. For your system that has 16GB RAM the size of the swap file is at least 4GB. If hibernation is enabled the size of the swap file could be 20GB-32GB.

Open the built-in Disk Usage Analyzer by clicking on its icon in the Dash and click on the ext4 partition. Then wait a few minutes for Disk Usage Analyzer to make a pie chart showing what is taking up the remainder of the used space on the 506GB ext4 partition.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Hi, I have attached a picture after running the command. could you please confirm me everything is okay with my new laptop? I have not used it even for a day.

Comment: so basically how much free space I have? I dont understand still. 506 gb?

Comment: I added this information to the end of my answer. Use the built-in Disk Usage Analyzer to make a chart that shows what is using the non-free space on the 506GB ext4 partition

Answer (score 1):

To find out what partitions you have and the available space on these open a terminal by pressing `ALT`+`STRG`+`T`

In the terminal type the diskfree command:

```
df -h
```

Have a look at the entries starting with `/dev`

If you want help resizing partitions, post the output here and I'll have a look at it and maybe make a suggestion.